# Probability of sum of product of uniform R.V.

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Suppose uniform[0,1] random variables $X_i$, $i=1,...,\infty$ are also independent. Whats the following probability?

\begin{split}
P\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^nX_i<\infty\Big)
\end{split}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right) < \infty.$$ What does this tell you about $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i < \infty \right)$$ ....?

Answer (score 2):

Following saz's hint, we have that since the $X_i$ are nonnegative, we can interchange the order of the expectation and summation, in which case,
\begin{align*}
E \sum_{n \geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{n \geq 1} E \prod_{i=1}^n X_i.
\end{align*}
Since the $X_i$ are independent, each with mean $1/2$, the above is equal to
\begin{align*}
= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1.
\end{align*}
Hence $\sum_{n\geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ has finite expectation. From here it is clear that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i < \infty$ with probability $1$, since otherwise, the expectation would be infinite. Hence,
\begin{align*}
P(\sum_{n\geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i < \infty) = 1.
\end{align*}